# Conflicting Definitions and Pattern Matching in typeclass instance declaration

Tags: haskell, typeclass

So, I'm Trying to write a typeclass instance for a type I've made and I'm running into issues.

```
data PlusMinus a = Plus a | Minus a | Zero
deriving(Eq,Show)
```

Essentialy we've got a type that has 3 different data constructors and the instance of `Num` should behave differently based on those different constructors.

```
instance (Ord a, Eq a,Num a) => Num (PlusMinus a) where
    Plus a + Plus b = Plus (a + b)
    Plus a - Plus b
        | a > b  = Plus (a - b)
        | a == b = Zero
        | a < b  = Minus (b - a)
    Plus a * Plus b = Plus (a * b)
    abs (Plus a)    = Plus (a)
    signum (Plus a) = 1
    fromInteger a
        | a > 0  = Plus (fromInteger a)
        | a == 0 = Zero
        | a < 0  = Minus (fromInteger . abs $ a)
```

So, Up to here it works fine, and behaves like expected, but when I add

```
Minus a + Minus b = Minus (a + b)
```

Suddenly I am told i have conflicting definitions for `+`.
Why doesn't this work like pattern matching for function definitions?
Does it work the same way and I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: Err, is the indentation _exactly_ like that? That being said, all patterns should stand next to each other, e.g. all `k + v`, then all `k - v` and so on.

Comment: Oops, I should have fixed the indention in the question, my real code was indented differently. I'll try changing the order of the lines. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! it was the line order that did it. If i move the `Minus a + Minus b ...` up to just below  `Plus a + Plus b ...` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function `f`, all patterns of the function must be next to each other:

```
f 1 'a' = 0
f 1 'b' = 1
f k v   = 2
```

If you add a pattern of another function in-between, you have multiple declarations:

```
f 1 'a' = 0
f 1 'b' = 1

whoops k = "hello"

f k v   = 2 -- error here
```

So put all your `+` patterns next to each other.